# How to Combine Same ID with its Quantity in Multiple array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to combine same variant_id with its quantity and price from multiple array to one new array in PHP.

Currently, I have same `variant_ids` are '**30929149493321, 19663805153353**' in the sample data.

The Output Array should be combined the same variant_id with its quantity and price.

**Input:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 30929149493321
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 299.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 19663805153353
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 99.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 19663804989513
            [quantity] => 6
            [price] => 99.00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 30929149493321
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 299.00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 19663805153353
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 99.00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 31108834754633
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 379.05
        )
)
```

**Desired output:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 30929149493321
            [quantity] => 2
            [price] => 299.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 19663805153353
            [quantity] => 2
            [price] => 99.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 19663804989513
            [quantity] => 6
            [price] => 99.00
        )    

    [3] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 31108834754633
            [quantity] => 1
            [price] => 379.05
        )
)
```

Comment: where's the code that needs fixing?

Comment: In you're question you forgot to mention how the combination of price and quantity should work. Should quantities be added? Should prices be averaged? Or how?

Comment: Price will be same only quantities will be added for same variant_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code example below creates a new empty array `$combined`. It iterates over each element of your array (`$array` in the `foreach` should be replaced with your array name) and searches in the new `$combined` array if there is already an entry with the actual `quantity_id`. If it exists, it combines the two `quantities`. If it not exists, it pushes the actual `values` to the `$combined` array. Your desired result is stored in `$combined`.

```
$combined = array();
foreach( $array as $values )  {
  if( ( $key = array_search( $values['variant_id'], array_column( $combined, 'variant_id') ) ) !== false )  {
    $combined[$key]['quantity'] += $values['quantity'];
  } else {
    $combined[] = $values;
  }
}
```